# Sharepoint Permissions using client side scripting

Tags: permissions

Can we inherit permission or provide permission to the SP group in a subsite, using client side scripting?

Comment: using javascript

Answer (score 1):

Using Client Object Model C#, you can give permission to a group in site/sub-site in the following way

```
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection/MyWebSite");
        Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;

        Principal oGroup = oWebsite.SiteGroups.GetByName("Group Name");

        RoleDefinition oRoleDefinition = oWebsite.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Create and Manage Alerts");
        RoleDefinitionBindingCollection collRoleDefinitionBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext);
        collRoleDefinitionBinding.Add(oRoleDefinition);

        RoleAssignment oRoleAssignment = oWebsite.RoleAssignments.Add(oGroup, collRoleDefinitionBinding);

        clientContext.Load(oGroup,
            user => user.Title);

        clientContext.Load(oRoleDefinition,
            role => role.Name);

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        Console.WriteLine("{0} added with {1} role.", oGroup.Title, oRoleDefinition.Name);
```

[How to: Work with Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee535915(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Huh Thanks..But can we do it using javascript and SP services

Comment: not sure about SP services. I hope it is possible using javascript. check msdn

Comment: Huh Okay fine...Thanx anyways